# How to reuse SASS style

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I am building a ReactJS app and using Zurb Foundation 6.  I am also using React Modal: https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/#documentation.

I want to style the Modal launched through React Modal to look like Zurb Foundation's Reveal.  The Reveal SASS looks like this:

```
// 28. Reveal
// ----------

$reveal-background: $white;
$reveal-width: 600px;
$reveal-max-width: $global-width;
$reveal-padding: $global-padding;
$reveal-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$reveal-radius: $global-radius;
$reveal-zindex: 1005;
$reveal-overlay-background: rgba($black, 0.45);
```

And my Modal CSS is like this:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  background-color: $white;
}

.OverlayClass {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba($black, 0.45);
}
```

How can I achieve this?  I have been experimenting with @include, but no success.  At the moment, the Modal I have is not aesthetically pleasing.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
.your-modal {
@extend .reveal;

/* write your custom css here */
}
```

instead of using `.reveal`, now you just need to use the start `.your-modal` for a modal container.

Answer (score 0):

The foundation section you have there is just the config variables for the reveal. The rest of the .scss for the reveal is here https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/components/_reveal.scss

You should be able to structure the rendered HTML from your component to match the elements and classes from Foundation, just avoid the Foundation JS.